# Stop Solspace freeform injecting a validation script

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, validation

I'd like to use Bootstrap validation with my Solspace Freeform, but I can't figure how to stop Freeform from adding it's default validation script to the page.

I've tried using a custom form template but it still injects the script, I don't want javascript injected into the middle of a page, and it conflicts with the Bootstrap script that is used throughout the site.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious which scripts you're specifically referring to? There's possibly a few different things that Freeform might insert, but it sounds to me like the one that would be most likely to interfere would be the "Disable Submit Button on Form Submit" feature.

This can actually be disabled by going to EE CP -> Add-ons -> Freeform -> Settings -> General
And then disabling the **Disable Submit Button on Form Submit** setting.

Let me know if you're referring to something else though. :)

Comment: MAybe it's not a validation script, but it triggers when the form is submitted and I thought it was validating the entered data, it's the code in the 'form-submit.js' file (fixed the issue by commenting that out for mow).

Comment: That's the Disable Submit Button on Form Submit setting. Instead of commenting out the line, just disable the setting.